# Flutter flutter_inappwebview showing some error in upload file code

Tags: flutter, dart, android-webview

i embedded my website in flutter app using  flutter_inappwebview, now it showing me some error.
the endwith and addCrossOriginResourcePolicy(CrossOriginResourcePolicy are underline red.
the  onFileChooser and   also showing error message.
i changed my sdkversion and i also have uploaded my dependency which they didn't thawing error where i add my package above

[image]
//////////////

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';

class MyWebView extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWebView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyWebViewState createState() => _MyWebViewState();
}

class _MyWebViewState extends State<MyWebView> {
  late final InAppWebViewController _webViewController;

  Future<void> _uploadFile() async {
    final result = await _webViewController.evaluateJavascript(source: 'document.getElementById("myFileInput").click();');
    print(result);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: InAppWebView(
          initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(url: Uri.parse('https://server.institutecms.com/')),
          onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
            _webViewController = controller;
          },
          androidOnPermissionRequest: (controller, origin, resources) async {
            return PermissionRequestResponse(
              resources: resources,
              action: PermissionRequestResponseAction.GRANT,
            );
          },
          onLoadStart: (controller, url) {},
          onLoadStop: (controller, url) {},
          onConsoleMessage: (controller, consoleMessage) {
            print(consoleMessage);
          },
          onLoadResource: (controller, resource) async {
            if (resource.url?.endsWith('.css') || resource.url.endsWith('.js')) {
              final headers = {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'};
              await controller.addCrossOriginResourcePolicy(CrossOriginResourcePolicy.ALLOW, resource.url, headers);
            }
          },
          onFileChooser: (controller, params) async {
            return await showDialog<FileChooserParams>(
              context: context,
              builder: (context) {
                return AlertDialog(
                  title: Text('Choose a file'),
                  content: Text('Select a file to upload'),
                  actions: [
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      },
                      child: Text('Cancel'),
                    ),
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.pop(context, params);
                      },
                      child: Text('OK'),
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              },
            );
          },
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: _uploadFile,
          child: Icon(Icons.file_upload),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the exact error message you're getting?

Comment: I want to embed my website in the fluter web flow but when I run. it shows on mobile when I login into the website using the app then inside the app nothing is clickable some part is clickable but some are not clickable. can you come to Gmail i will provide you more info